# How do you capture mobs that come from the End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a mob display in Minecraft, and I want all the mobs to be displayed in cages. I use a spawn egg or commands to get the mobs in the cages. Then I put a Name Tag on them so they don't despawn. However, I can't figure out how to cage Endermen, Endermites, and Shulkers since they can teleport. Could somebody tell me how to cage them (if it's possible), even if it uses commands or mods/downloads?

Comment: Try put them in minecarts and see if they can still teleport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a bedrock cage with a 1x1 hole with glass inside, the mobs should not tp. I tested this on endermen, since I have MC 1.7.10. If it doesn't work, use this:

```
/summon YOURMOB ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}
```